# Linq to sql query multiple inheritance

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

This is the database schema: [image: Database schema]

I have this problem, I try to get only the data from the Group table who also belong to GroupB, so I use `!g.IdGroup.Equals(a.IdGroup)` for excluding GroupA data.
I checked that GroupA and GroupB IDs are in Group table, but I still get data from both tables. How could I fix this?  Sorry for my bad english, and for my poor sql/linq knowledge.

```
var result = from a in db.GroupA
             from r in db.Registration
             join g in db.Group on r.IdGroup equals g.IdGroup
             where !g.IdGroup.Equals(a.IdGroup)
             select new {
                 g.Name
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

by looking at the LINQ , shouldn't be like that ?

```
var result = from a in db.GroupA
             join r in db.Registration on a.IdGroup equals r.IdGroup             
             join g in db.Group on r.IdGroup equals g.IdGroup
             where !g.IdGroup.Equals(a.IdGroup)
             select new {
                 g.Name
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the equivalent to a NOT IN, in SQL, which is to say, a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    g.name
FROM
    Group g
WHERE
    g.IdGroup NOT IN (SELECT IDGroup FROM GroupA);
```

Does that look like what you want?

In that case, the equivalent LINQ can be achieved like this:

```
var result = from g in db.Group
             where !(from a in GroupA select a.IdGroup).Contains(g.IdGroup)
             select new {
                 g.Name
             };
```

Hope that helps.